# Choosing a CMS for an artist's site?

Tags: content-management-system, gallery

I'm looking for a simple CMS for a site I'm building for my girlfriend.
The requirements are very minimal

- Show images one by one, possibly with a line of text for each
- Show an aggregate gallery of say 4x4 images.
- Possibly have several different such galleries
- Customizable look so i could fit it to her mockup

Any suggestions come to mind?
Can wordpress do this?

Comment: *You* can be her CMS... The (propriety) Shoosh CMS! :P

Comment: How about a hosted solution like Squarespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use WordPress with some gallery plugins, for example: [NexGEN](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) or [kPicasa Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kpicasa-gallery/). Last is used for show pictures from your Picasa account.

Other option: [ZENPhoto](http://www.zenphoto.org/). Actually you can combine both WordPress and ZENPhoto in one site.

Answer (score 1):

You may think that it is simple - an dit is now. But can you predict the future?

If your gf is an artist, might she not want to sell? Then she'll need watermarking (now) and a shopping cart (when she decides to sell).

Does she want to speak about her art? She'll need a blog.

Does she want others to speak about her art, or art in general? Then a forum n (blog & forum will also attract viewers).

Etc, etc.

Why not consult the oracle at http://www.cmsmatrix.org/ ?  It's the best place to go to look for a CMS system.

Pick something simple & easy to set up & use, but be aware of possible future expansion features.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend [Cargo Collective](http://cargocollective.com/). It is a free, excellent Wordpress like alternative geared specifically for visual artists. After exploring numerous options, this is a great tool for those wishing to update their own content without dealing with technical things.

It even has built in network to highlight your site/art in the "collective".

http://cargocollective.com/

Answer (score 0):

For something this simple, with only a handful of pages, it almost seems like overkill to use a CMS at all. Surely the added complexity of a huge application like WordPress isn't called for here.

Answer (score 0):

Well MOvE Online offers an all-in-one package. And you don't need to have technical skills to install plugins or whatever, because it's already build in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for one now, but just in case-- I'm an artist and I built a simple PHP CMS (no database) for myself recently. Just create folders / add image files / edit text files to manage content. It was pretty useful for me so I decided to release it as open source, it's called [Gallerina](http://feanne.com/gallerina). No automatic thumbnails and no pagination, but it's pretty easy to use and the default style is simple and elegant, good for a visual artist's portfolio. :)

If you're looking for something more robust, you can check out [Stacey](http://www.staceyapp.com/) (simple elegant interface too, but you can add content other than images) or MiniGal (automatic thumbnails).

Answer (score 0):

Stacey http://www.staceyapp.com/ is a very simplicistic approach, but it needs basic markup skills.

Secretary CMS http://www.secretarycms.com/ is an easy to use CMS specially crafted for designers, artists, photographers and musicians.

Answer (score 0):

I never used it, but while I was looking for some CMS for photographers I found this [koken](http://koken.me/) which looks pretty pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I use [koken](http://koken.me/) since three months, it's still in beta, but has already a nice interface to manage your pictures. It also allows you to create own template and plugins.